# Global Types are not recognised in Angular in selective cases (Cannot find name)

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I'm building a pretty standard Angular 15 Application and for some reason some types I've created are not available at build time.

I've stored my types in the `src/types` folder and included the following in my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    },
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the type files in that folder

```js
type Person = {
  name: string
}
```

Some of my code that's not in the `app` directory is stored in a directory a such as: `src/domain/general/file.ts`

At this point, everything works fine, and all my tests run well, however, whenever I create a service that references the nested `file.ts` , then add that service as a provider, Typescript cannot find the **Person** type that I created above.

In fact, when doing an **ng-build** that file throws the error:

> src/domain/general/file.ts:16:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Person'

Ideally I'd like to use certain typings without having to import them each time, and I have tried a few solutions already, including

- creating a global.d.ts file and declaring the types there
- changing different variations of the typeRoots path.

The only *"hacky"* solution that I've found, is to use globbing in the `tsconfig.app.json` to include all files regardless of how deeply they are nested.
This is not ideal as that file should only reference entry points and it throws a million warnings for files being compiled and not in use just yet

Comment: Let's say the file you created is `src/types/example.d.ts`. But you didn't add `"types": ["example"]` to your `tsconfig.lib.json`. Also, I've experienced that `tsconfig.json` doesn't work, but `tsconfig.lib.json` does for some reason

Comment: @Pieterjan i just tried it, no dice...

Comment: You say first that TS is configured to look for your types under `src/types`, and then say the type you are having an issue with is stored as `src/domain/general/file.ts`. Well, that's not under `src/types`, so that's why it's not getting picked up. Is there a reason you're not just using `import type from 'wherever';`? Then you can store your types wherever you want...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not sure if I"m doing it right, but I wanted to make the types globally available to all parts of the angular app. If I were to actually run all the unit tests on that same `src/domain/general/file.ts` it all tests fine. 
My assumption was that once there is an entrypoint in the tsconfig all would then be imported through that, using the globally available types

Comment: I would suggest just importing it at the top of the file like normal.  If you feel like your files have too many lines of imports going on, maybe that's an indication that things need to be broken up more rather than finding a way to hide how many things a particular file depends on.

Comment: @JakeSmith I think that's where I'll end up having to go with this one.